# How to make a change to the variable `glasses-separator` take effect?

Tags: utf-8

I have the following elisp function that uses utf8 hex codes to change the separator used by `glasses-mode`.

One problem is that simply calling `(setq glasses-separator "\u27A4")` is not displaying the utf symbol.  I also want the user to have the ability of choosing a utf code from a list.

```
(defun camelsens ()
  "Splits CamelCase phrases using separator."

  (interactive)
  (glasses-mode 0) 
  (setq glasses-separator "\u27A4")
  (glasses-mode 1))
```

Comment: Select how, from what list? Interactively? This seems to be a dup of questions you've asked before, about how to interactively choose a value from a list of choices. The answer is to use `completing-read` in and `interactive` spec.

Comment: how does it now work? what do you expect? what is it doing that you don't expect?

Comment: each time you call `(glasses-mode)` you toggle its state.

Comment: Looking at the defcustom, I cannot simply assign the value to this variable.

Comment: You changed the question after @Drew's comment (which is not a good idea in general), but you did not change the title or the tags. The second half of the question answers the first half, and my answer answers the second half only. Can you see why that is a very bad way of doing things? If somebody is looking to see why changing the glasses separator did not work, how would they find this question and its answer?

Comment: I shall change it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commentary in glasses.el says:

```
;; If you set any of the variables `glasses-separator' or `glasses-face' after
;; glasses.el is loaded in a different way than through customize, you
;; should call the function `glasses-set-overlay-properties' afterwards.
```

So try calling the function after your `setq` and see what happens.

AFAICT, you don't need to turn off `glasses-mode` and turn it back on again:

```el
(defun camelsens (hexcode)
  "Splits CamelCase phrases using separator."

  (interactive
   (list (completing-read "Utf8_hex_code: " 
       '("\u27A4" "\u25BA" "\u2192") nil t "\u2192")))

  (setq glasses-separator hexcode)
  (glasses-set-overlay-properties))
```